# Crawler skipping content of the first page

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

I've created a crawler which is parsing certain content from a website.

Firstly, it scrapes links to the category from left-sided bar.

secondly, it harvests the whole links spread through pagination connected to the profile page

And finally, going to each profile page it scrapes name, phone and web address.

So far, it is doing well. The only problem I see with this crawler is that It always starts scraping from the second page skipping the first page. I suppose there might be any way I can get this around. Here is the complete code I am trying with:

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url="https://www.houzz.com/professionals/"

def category_links(mainurl):
    req=requests.Session()
    response = req.get(mainurl).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    for titles in tree.xpath("//a[@class='sidebar-item-label']/@href"):
        next_pagelink(titles)   # links to the category from left-sided bar


def next_pagelink(process_links):
    req=requests.Session()
    response = req.get(process_links).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    for link in tree.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//a[@class='pageNumber']/@href"):
        profile_pagelink(link)      # the whole links spread through pagination connected to the profile page


def profile_pagelink(procured_links):
    req=requests.Session()
    response = req.get(procured_links).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    for titles in tree.xpath("//div[@class='name-info']"):
        links = titles.xpath(".//a[@class='pro-title']/@href")[0]
        target_pagelink(links)         # profile page of each link


def target_pagelink(main_links):
    req=requests.Session()
    response = req.get(main_links).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)

    def if_exist(titles,xpath):
        info=titles.xpath(xpath)
        if info:
            return info[0]
        return ""

    for titles in tree.xpath("//div[@class='container']"):
        name = if_exist(titles,".//a[@class='profile-full-name']/text()")
        phone = if_exist(titles,".//a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' click-to-call-link ')]/@phone")
        web = if_exist(titles,".//a[@class='proWebsiteLink']/@href")
        print(name,phone,web)

category_links(url)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the first page is that it doesn't have a 'pagination' class so this expression : `tree.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']//a[@class='pageNumber']/@href")` returns an empty list and the `profile_pagelink` function never gets executed.

As a quick fix you can handle this case separately in the `category_links` function :

```
def category_links(mainurl):
    response = requests.get(mainurl).text
    tree = html.fromstring(response)
    if mainurl == "https://www.houzz.com/professionals/": 
        profile_pagelink("https://www.houzz.com/professionals/")
    for titles in tree.xpath("//a[@class='sidebar-item-label']/@href"):
        next_pagelink(titles)
```

Also i noticed that the `target_pagelink` prints a lot of empty strings as a result of `if_exist` returning `""` . You can skip those cases if you add a condition in the for loop :

```
for titles in tree.xpath("//div[@class='container']"):    # use class='profile-cover' if you get douplicates #
    name = if_exist(titles,".//a[@class='profile-full-name']/text()")
    phone = if_exist(titles,".//a[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' click-to-call-link ')]/@phone")
    web = if_exist(titles,".//a[@class='proWebsiteLink']/@href")
    if name+phone+web : 
        print(name,phone,web)
```

Finally `requests.Session` is mostly used for storing cookies and other headers which is not necessary for your script. You can just use `requests.get` and have the same results.

Comment: Thanks sir t.m.adam, for your quick, robust and effective solution. It fixes every single problem I could think of. Heavily indebted to you for this. One thing to know for clarity that is: which url is being used in the bracket profile_pagelink(url). Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: It's the `url` defined in the 3rd line of your script ( `"https://www.houzz.com/professionals/"` ). I updated my code to make it clear. Because of the python scope rules the `profile_pagelink` function can access the value of `url` .

Comment: As mainurl and url both are same in this case so if i use mainurl i'm getting same results. Is there any difference between the two, i meant programmatically?

Comment: The `mainurl` is an argument to `category_links` while `url` is a variable . So `mainurl` has a local scope ( it only exists inside `category_links` ) , and `url` has global scope. But If you allways call `category_links` with `url` as an argument, then it makes no difference at all.

Comment: Hi sir t.m.adam, hope you are doing fine. In your spare time, please check out the link. "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45131395/unable-to-write-extracted-items-properly-in-an-excel-file" .Thanks in advance.