# Unable to write extracted items properly in an excel file?

Tags: python, excel, xpath, web-scraping, lxml

I've written some code in python to parse title and link from a webpage. Initially, I tried to parse the links from the left sided bar then scrape those aforesaid documents from each page by tracking down each links. I did this flawlessly. I tried to save the documents of different links in different pages in a single excel file. However, It creates several "Sheets" extracting the desired portion as the sheet name from heading variable from my script. The problem I'm facing is- when the data are saved, only the last record of each page from the links are saved in my excel sheets instead of the full records. Here is the script I tried with:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from pyexcel_ods3 import save_data

web_link = "http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/videos/"
main_url = "http://www.wiseowl.co.uk"

def get_links(page):

    response = requests.Session().get(page)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
    data = {}
    titles = tree.xpath("//ul[@class='woMenuList']//li[@class='woMenuItem']/a/@href")
    for title in titles:
        if "author" not in title and "year" not in title:
            get_docs(data, main_url + title)

def get_docs(data, url):

    response = requests.Session().get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)

    heading = tree.findtext('.//h1[@class="gamma"]')

    for item in tree.xpath("//p[@class='woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle']"):
        title = item.findtext('.//a')
        link = item.xpath('.//a/@href')[0]
        # print(title, link)
        data.update({heading.split(" ")[-4]: [[(title)]]})
    save_data("mth.ods", data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_links(web_link)
```

Comment: Come again? A csv file does not have multiple sheets, unlike excel.

Comment: It seems to me the glaring error here is you forget to call `outfile.close()` once you're done writing to the csv.

Comment: Right you are sir,  cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ. I am very new on this. It should be in an excel file. Gonna edit the title.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? How is `save_data()` defined and where are you calling it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Sir alecxe, you can now check out my script. I'm almost there. Now the script is able to produce several sheets and name it extracting the desired portion from heading variable. However, the problem is each sheet contains the last record of each link when everything is done. How can i get full results of each links? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you update the values in the `data` dict the previous values get replaced.

You can fix this if you replace this line:

```
data.update({heading.split(" ")[-4]: [[(title)]]})
```

With this ( it's a bit ugly but it works ) :

```
data[heading.split(" ")[-4]] = data.get(heading.split(" ")[-4], []) + [[(title)]]
```

Comment: You beat me by 8 mins of one day old post :)

Comment: Thanks sir t.m.adam, for caring to answer. Your answer made me speechless again. One last thing to urge: you perhaps noticed that I could not use the "link" parameter in [(title)]. Could you tell me how to place the both? I meant, [(title, link)] something like this.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't help you with that. I have 0 experience with the `pyexcel_ods3` lib, sorry.

Comment: Don't bother sir t.m.adam. You have always been a great help to me.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you would like it to be more readable:

```
def get_docs(data, url):

    response = requests.Session().get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(response.text)

    heading = tree.findtext('.//h1[@class="gamma"]')

    for item in tree.xpath("//p[@class='woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle']"):
        title = item.findtext('.//a')
        sheetname = heading.split(" ")[-4]
        if sheetname in data:  
            data[sheetname].append([title])  
        else:  
            data[sheetname] = [[title]]
    save_data("mth.ods", data)
```

**Edit:** To insert `link` to the next column, you should simply add it to your list like this:

```
if sheetname in data:  
    data[sheetname].append([title, str(link)])  
else:  
    data[sheetname] = [[title, str(link)]]
```

**Edit2:** To have them on the same page, you need to append them to the same key, since key represents sheet and value represents rows and columns in `save_data`. Like this:

```
sheetname = 'You are welcome'
for item in tree.xpath("//p[@class='woVideoListDefaultSeriesTitle']"):
            title = item.findtext('.//a')
            if sheetname in data:  
                data[sheetname].append([title])  
            else:  
                data[sheetname] = [[title]]
        save_data("mth.ods", data)
```

Comment: OMG!!! Who is it I got in the loop. Too many giants in a single thread. Thanks Tehscript, for your answer. It works. I tested it already.

Comment: @SMth80 thanks, please see my edit for usage of your `link` parameter.

Comment: You are really the wizard, Tehscript. It works like charm. You are in real trouble from now on cause I didn't know so far that you also provide solution in python thread as well:). Thanks once again.

Comment: Python is one of the languages I frequently use for scraping web and data manipulation. I am not a newbie in python, but not an expert as well, so I usually don't jump into things and leave the stage to such masters like t.m.adam

Comment: One last favor on this, Tehscript. What If there were no sheetname parameter in the script and data to be saved in a single sheet. How would that expression be? Can't find any idea. Sorry for the botheration and thanks in advance.

Comment: @SMth80 see Edit2

Comment: You are one of the most knowledgeable and helpful persons I've ever come across in my entire life. It works like magic. I've searched through different websites to get a clear knowledge on this and your style turns out to be the best one to go through. Hats off to you.

Comment: Thank you, you are very kind.